# Erro ao instalar projeto React Native no celular

Tags: android-studio, react-native, ubuntu

Boa noite, pessoal!
Seguinte, eu iniciei os estudos em react native há pouco tempo. Segui todos os passos do site oficial para instalação de softwares e dependências:
Android Studio e o Android SDK, NodeJS + NPM (no meu caos eu instalei o Yarn, tamém) e o Java JDK stable (11.0.4, a versão mais recente).
Eu voi por o print das versões junto pra facilitar. E fiz, também, a inclusão da variável de ambiente do android_home, no .bash_profile (eu uso Ubuntu 19.04).

O caso é que, teoricamente, estou com tudo "em dia" mas não consigo fazer a aplicação rodar no meu celular e nem por emulador. Em ambas as situção o erro que recebo é de falha ao encontrar o caminho do SDK, como se ele não existisse. Preciso muito de uma ajuda pois ja até tenho um possível job em vista que vai precisar desse conhecimento.. 
[image: as versões dos programas/gerenciadores de pacotes]

[image: O erro..eu precisei diminuir o tamanho pra q coubesse numa imagem só]

[image: O erro... eu reduzi um pouco o tamanho pra caber numa imagem]

Comment: Infelizmente, devo estar fazendo algo errado pois não consigo colocar mais que duas fotos... como descrevi, os caminhos estão configurados e se for necessário posso mandar print de como fiz a configuração.. o fato é que preciso resolver isso o quanto antes.

Comment: Versão do java deve ser a 8